# Sliding Div Left to Right

Tags: javascript, slide

I have a slider that slides the content from the top to bottom when a link/button is clicked. I want it to slide out from the right side of the button and move left to right. Is this possible by just adjusting the code I already have? Thanks.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>jQuery Accordion Style DIV Menu</title>
<link href="format.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="text.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div class="accordionButton">Button 1 Content</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">Content 1<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Long Example</div>
    <div class="accordionButton">Button 2 Content</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">Content 2<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Medium Example</div>
    <div class="accordionButton">Button 3 Content</div>

    <div class="accordionContent">Content 1<br />Short Example</div>
    <div class="accordionButton">Button 4 Content</div>
    <div class="accordionContent">Content 4<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Extra Long Example</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

javascript.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//ACCORDION BUTTON ACTION (ON CLICK DO THE FOLLOWING)
$('.accordionButton').click(function() {

    //REMOVE THE ON CLASS FROM ALL BUTTONS
    $('.accordionButton').removeClass('on');

    //NO MATTER WHAT WE CLOSE ALL OPEN SLIDES
    $('.accordionContent').slideUp('normal');

    //IF THE NEXT SLIDE WASN'T OPEN THEN OPEN IT
    if($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {

        //ADD THE ON CLASS TO THE BUTTON
        $(this).addClass('on');

        //OPEN THE SLIDE
        $(this).next().slideDown('normal');
     } 

 });


/*** REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/

//ADDS THE .OVER CLASS FROM THE STYLESHEET ON MOUSEOVER 
$('.accordionButton').mouseover(function() {
    $(this).addClass('over');

//ON MOUSEOUT REMOVE THE OVER CLASS
}).mouseout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass('over');                                      
});

/*** END REMOVE IF MOUSEOVER IS NOT REQUIRED ***/


/********************************************************************************************************************
CLOSES ALL S ON PAGE LOAD
********************************************************************************************************************/   
$('.accordionContent').hide();

});
```

Comment: maybe this link can help http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Comment: @A.B.Cade The problem with that example is I'm not sure how to have the button outside of the div and still work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, and for what you're triyng to do, I would recommend a plug-in. Maybe caroFredSel or nivo:
http://nivo.dev7studios.com/

This will make your life WAY easier.

Comment: That isn't quite the slider I was looking for. Pretty much trying to get a slider like this site has http://www.grano.hu/

Comment: Those will be wicked easier to edit, than what you have... I can help with what you have if you'd like, but it'll be adding a bunch of code to handle something these sliders already do.

Comment: Also, try using some CSS to handle all the spacing done by those <br /> tags... that's killing your parse time (not that that specific file is heavy, just something for you to keep in your mind as you develop) And You're Welcome!

Answer (score 2):

check this:

http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

there explains differents slides

Comment: Ya i saw that example, but is it possible to move the button outside of the div and still make it work?

Comment: Yeah that would be possible, you just need to be able to reference the button and the sliding content, be it relative to another element or absolute by ID, for example.

Comment: @c24w I don't really understand sorry

Answer (score 0):

Use this ,

```
 $('.accordionButton').click(function() {
    $(this).next().animate({width: 'toggle'});
  });
```